# Table in jQuery with toggable row

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a table with the list of orders in my ecommerce site. I would like another line to appear with the order details by clicking on each line. 
I don't understand how to write the function.

Here is how i wrote the table row:

```
$("#tbody").append("<tr id='riga" + i + "'><th scope='row'>" + idordine 
    + "</th><td>" + data + "</td><td>" + prezzoTotale 
    + "€</td><td> <button id='button_" + i 
    + "')>Dettagli</button></tr><tr id='orderdetail_" + i 
    + "' style='display:none;'>"
    + "<th scope='row'> ciao </th><td>ciao2</td><td>ciao2</td><td>ciao2</td></tr>"
);
```

and the function i wrote is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ordini.length; i++) {
    $("#button_" + i).click(function(i) {
        $("#orderdetail_" + i).toggle("slow");

    });
}
```

the variable i in  `$("#orderdetail_"+i)` doesn't work. How can i do it? 
**Thanks all.**

Comment: `click(function(i) {` is not how you define an event handler.  Just use `$(this).closest("tr").next().toggle()`

Comment: @freedomn-m, why not? The `click()` method is very useful in that way.

Comment: Davide, you might add your data variables here and show us what's happening: https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/91uydzb0/

Comment: @isherwood never used that overload, but wouldn't it be `$("button").click(i, function(i) { ..` ?

Comment: I don't follow. The single-argument handler function implementation is probably the most common. It's listed first: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @isherwood and what's `i` in that case?  `Event eventObject` - not `i` the loop counter - as in `.click(function(el) { $(el)...`

Comment: ok , with '$(this).closest("tr").next().toggle()'  is working. But i prefer to use the 'i' reference. How can i pass the value of 'i' in the function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to link button_i with orderdetail_i, you can use relative navigation, in this case a relatively simple:

```
$(this).closest("tr").next()
```

To facilitate the event handler, I've added `togglebutton` class to each button and used that in a single selector.

Updated code:

```js
// setup some example data
for (var i = 1;i<10; ++i) {
  $("tbody").append("<tr id='riga" + i + "'><th scope='row'>" + "idordine"
    + "</th><td>" + "data" + "</td><td>" + "prezzoTotale"
    + "€</td><td> <button class='togglebutton' id='button_" + i 
    + "')>Dettagli</button></tr><tr id='orderdetail_" + i 
    + "' style='display:none;'>"
    + "<th scope='row'> ciao </th><td>ciao" + i + "</td><td>ciao" + i + "</td><td>ciao" + i + "</td></tr>"
  ); 
}

// handle toggle
$("button.togglebutton").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").next().toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
</tbody>
<table>
```

Comment: Also known as "DOM traversal".